# Проблема при посылке файла от сервера в браузер на Java

Tags: java, веб-сервер

Пишу сервер на Java, который должен на дефолтный запрос браузера (т.е. без указания точного файла: `GET / HTTP/1.1`) просто отправить какое-нибудь сообщение, чтобы оно показалось на экране браузера. Вот мой код.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    System.out.println("connected");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    output.println("HTTP/1.1 200 connected");
    output.println();
    output.println("<HTML>");
    output.println("some messages");
    output.println("</HTML>");
}
```

Но когда в браузере (если что я использую Google Chrome) вбиваю `localhost:1234`, то браузер пишет, что *Не удается получить доступ к сайту*, хотя сама программа выводит *connected*.

Comment: Ваш код в порядке. Я даже проверил у себя, работает. Возможно, у вас в браузере прописан прокси.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без указания некоторых header'ов, типа Content-length, вряд ли будет работать.
Вообще в Java есть встроенный http сервер, о котором мало кто знает - это пакет **com.sun.net.httpserver.***

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class MyHttpServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create();
        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(1234), 0);
        server.createContext("/", httpExchange -> {
            String text = "<HTML>some messages</HTML>";
            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, text.length());
            OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
            os.write(text.getBytes());
            os.close();
        });
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: А если без этого пакета, то какие header'ы надо указать? (если можно, то покажи заодно, как это сделать, пожалуйста)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_заголовков_HTTP см.пункты 1,3,4 и таблицу. Больше ничем помочь не смогу.